# [Vue warn]: Invalid vnode type when creating vnode: undefined

Tags: vue.js, jsx, vuejs3

I'm getting this warning when trying to render icons dynamically. I added the code below. I will be glad if someone helps me to figure out the issue. Thanks

```js
<script>
import { Row, Col } from "ant-design-vue";
import { AnIcon } from "./IconStyled";
import * as Icons from "@ant-design/icons-vue";
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "AntdIcon",
  components: {
    AnIcon,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      Icons,
    };
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <Row gutter={15}>
        {Object.values(Icons)
          .filter(
            (item) =>
              item.name !== "default" &&
              item.name !== "setTwoToneColor" &&
              item.name !== "getTwoToneColor" &&
              item.name !== "canlendar" &&
              item.name !== "interation" &&
              item.name !== "colum-height" &&
              item.name !== "createFromIconfontCN"
          )
          .map((icon, key) => {
            const customTag = Icons[icon.name];
            return (
              <Col xl={6} md={12} xs={24} key={key + 1}>
                <AnIcon class="icon-single">
                  <customTag />
                  <span> {icon.name}</span>
                </AnIcon>
              </Col>
            );
          })}
      </Row>
    );
  },
});
</script>
```

**And here is the warning that I am facing right now.**

[image]

Comment: a quick guess is an item.name of undefined,

Comment: @Estradiaz the item.name is not undefined, it works fine. But the problem is in <customTag />, which dynamically generates svg icons.

Comment: ahh you mean you shoud use something like <component :is="Icons[icon.name]" /> ?